# Navigation Bar Not Fitting Full Width

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to get a navigation bar to stretch across the whole width of the screen when in portrait and landscape. To do this I added some constraints for the right and left border to be 0 pixels indent as follows;

[image]

However, this seems to still be failing and when I look at the view after changing there is an indent as can be seen in the following picture.

[image]

How can you stop this form happening so as to make the navigation bar stretch across the whole screen.

Thanks

Comment: Why not to create Navigation Bar with UINavigationController programmatically?

Comment: Because I am following a Tutorial and am only just beginning my iOS journey - Baby steps!

Comment: Yes (as seen in Screenshot) - i would suggest to implement a UINavigatioNController (in Storyboard) - just select your ViewController and go to "Editor - Embed in - Navigation Controller".

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I discovered that this is caused by the Navigation Bar's constraints being relative to the view's margin.

In order to fix it in the scene editor, select the constraint, then in the Utilities pane on the right, click on the "First Item" dropdown (should be Navigation Bar.Leading), then **uncheck** "Relative to margin".

Repeat on the other side.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it,

First remove constraints of the navigation bar and then again assign constraints by unchecking "constrain to margin" checkbox as shown below:

[image]

Assign the following four constraints(as shown in above image):

```
Top space to 0
Leading space to 0
Trailing space to 0
Height fixed to 64
```